# What is the best iPhone app for viewing Wikitravel offline?

Tags: online-resources, cellphones

I'm primarily looking for offline functionality when traveling (likely without internet connection); Map functionality would also be nice. FWIW, I also posted this question [on Quora](http://quora.com/Wikitravel/What-is-the-best-iPhone-app-for-Wikitravel).

Comment: Just so you know, the [Wikitravel project as it was has shifted to Wikivoyage](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/881/108).

Answer (score 2):

"Best" is relative. However, I'm quite happy with [Turdus](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/turdus-offline-wikitravel/id590503295?mt=8) for Wikitravel and [Wikivoyage](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wikivoyage-offline-world-travel/id650926734?mt=8) for, you've guessed it.

Both are fairly usable and work offline. And they're free.

I also recommend [mapswithme](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/mapswithme-lite.-offline-maps/id431183278?mt=8), for offline maps. There's a free version and a paid version which also allows you to search the maps, which is super useful (I'm not affiliated).